# Displaying Outlook Address book in Delphi XE app:

Tags: delphi, com, outlook, delphi-xe, outlook-2010

I have a Delphi XE app and I'd like to pop up the address book dialog that Outlook uses from within my Delphi app - I assume there are COM classes to support this? What's the best way to get this done? Platform is Win7-64 with Outlook 2010.

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: It is definitely possible to do so through COM, but *Outlook will display warnings that a 3rd party application is accessing the address book* (and rightfully so). If you want to avoid these warnings, you can run the code from within an Outlook add-in, resort to MAPI, or use [Outlook Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm), which is basically an advanced wrapper around MAPI that feels like the Outlook Object Model.

The Outlook Object Model offers the [SelectNamesDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb176400%28v=office.12%29.aspx) dialog to display the address book. It is highly configurable, and you can initialize it with custom sets of addresses as well.

As a little example, here is some code that pops up the address book in multiselect mode. For brevity, it uses late binding (OleVariants). You'll probably want to use early binding in production code.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  application: OleVariant;
  dialog: OleVariant;
  i: Integer;
  recipients: String;
  recipient: OleVariant;

begin
  application := createOleObject( 'Outlook.Application' );

  // Obtain the dialog
  dialog := application.session.getSelectNamesDialog;

  // Only show the a single 'add' field, multiselect
  dialog.setDefaultDisplayMode( 6 ); // 6 = olDefaultDelegates

  // Display the dialog
  dialog.display;

  // Display selection
  recipients := '';
  for i := 1 to dialog.recipients.count do
  begin
      recipient := dialog.recipients.item( i );

      recipients := recipients + recipient.name + #13#10;
  end;

  showMessage( recipients );
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for the detail - wasn't clear about MAPI being a different approach than Outlook object model - not up to speed on Office/Exchange integration, etc.

Answer (score 2):

To do something like this you need to support the Extended MAPI interface.

Here is a link to a component which supports this on Win7-64 Outlook-2010.

[Easy MAPI](http://www.rapware.nl/prod_easymapi_page1.asp?SubMenu=EasyMAPI)

Supports execution of address book dialogs.

Comment: +1 - I will probably end up using Easy MAPI but I gave the point to the other answer because @Paul-Jan explained the different options etc. Thanks.